# Is it valid to assume that a reference is passed as a pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, reference, arguments

I have a function defined like this:

```
void doSomethingWithCustomer (const Customer &customer);
```

One of my fellow developers called it like this:

```
Customer *customer = order.getCustomer();
doSomethingWithCustomer (*customer);
```

Unfortunately, the `getCustomer` method can return a nullptr, if the order is not tied to a customer.
If `getCustomer` returns a nullptr, then the application does not crash at the time of the call to `doSomethingWithCustomer` but rather within the function, where the customer reference is used.

Of course the correct way to write this is to check for customer not being a nullptr first, then call the function if we have a valid customer.
Normally we expect that if a function/method has a reference argument, that the caller checks the validity of it (which wasn't the case here), instead of the function itself checking the argument.

I know that Visual Studio 2010 (and earlier versions) passes references by actually passing the pointer, but I wonder if this is indicated somewhere in the C++ standard.  Can we assume that a reference is always passed as a pointer (personally, I wouldn't rely on this, but it's interesting to know it)?

Is it possible to tell Visual Studio that when passing a reference, it should automatically dereference it first and crash at the time of the call rather then somewhere much deeper (doing this in a debug version might be sufficient)?

Comment: I would have assumed it would crash at *customer itself..

Comment: No use can't assume that. The code has undefined behaviour because you are dereferencing a NULL pointer. Anything after that is undefined.

Comment: @KarthikT No, reading from address zero is generally not a problem, it's writing that will cause crashes and burning.

Comment: Also subject to the as-if rule. The thing with references is, the compiler can generate code that doesn't pass neither a pointer or a reference, as long as the observable effects of the code is unaltered

Comment: AFAIK, any attempt to access the state of the object that is passed in will cause the crash (say calling a member function which reads some state.) Normally calling a function that accesses no state may proceed without any crashes, but you are just depending on undefined behaviour - if a function expects a reference, it should be to something valid - anyone not passing in anything valid - needs a serious talking to!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I see! thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: No, a read crashes too.  Problem is that it doesn't read.  Use assert() liberally.

Comment: @HansPassant I think it's actually Undefined Behaviour. So, if you're unlucky, it won't crash and raptors will have a field day. (There's no such thing as a nullptr dereference, many implementations/architectures will map to virtual address 0x00000000 _but_ a pointer may not even _be_ an architecture-specific address, e.g. on Hell++)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Is it valid to assume that a reference is passed as a pointer?**

No, it is not.
The standard does not mandate that the reference should be implemented in terms of pointer.

How to actually implement a reference is an implementation detail which the standard leaves out for implementations to decide on. It only describes the expected behavior from an Reference and one of them is a reference can never be `NULL` in a standard conformant program.

If your function parameter is expected to be `NULL` sometimes then you should pass it as an pointer.

Comment: "one of them is a reference can never be NULL in a standard conformant program" -- and thus for example if you put `if (&customer == 0) throw logic_error("null reference");` then the optimizer is permitted to remove the whole statement, since it's a condition that is always false in a program with defined behavior, followed by dead code.

Comment: Just what I thought.  I need to have a serious talk with somebody.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's completely implementation defined.

For diagnostic purposes, I've created a little container type which validates the parameter. You would then declare the function/method:

```
void doSomethingWithCustomer(const t_nonnull<const Customer>& pCustomer);
```

where the `t_nonnull` type validated the parameter at construction. However, I've found it more useful to just use references more and more frequently (IOW, don't return a pointer in this case -- just consider it an error to access the customer when the customer does not exist).

Comment: Interesting idea. Though I generally dislike language-uglifying syntax conventions (such as [the `in<T>` convention proposed by some (around p.29](http://www.slideshare.net/SumantTambe/c11-idioms-silicon-valley-code-camp-2012)) this might be useful when judiciously used.

Comment: @sehe yeah, i expanded on it -- just using references in most any case is a much cleaner, IMO. however, the concept can be taken further to perform other validation. that can save a lot of parameter precondition checking at entries. the ability to move in the link is kinda cool -- also judiciously :)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is undefined. That means that you cannot rely on any particular way of discovering the error. A good compiler might be able to warn you at compile time, while another one might mask the error completely, depending on how you use the variable. It is your responsibility to make sure that references are never NULL.

Answer (score 1):

It's not observable, and it's irrelevant. A program using this code has undefined behavior because it dereferences a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Reference *might* be implemented using pointer internally (like what happens in Java). But below 2 difference are crucial between them:

1. By default a pointer can be rebind to the other object. However
   reference has a permanent binding with the object it was initialized
2. A pointer can be assigned with 0, but a reference cannot

Analogically `T&` is equivalent to `T* const`.

You don't need to inform compiler about deferencing a variable, because that happens by yourself.

```
void foo(T&);

T t, *p = 0;
foo(t); // the only way to pass reference
foo(*p); // the only way to pass reference
```

Comment: I think your statement re Java might be suspect. The JVM can move objects in memory and so I suspect a Java reference may be a pointer to a pointer

Comment: @BrianAgnew - a pointer to a pointer is not required for moving things in memory. A garbage collector knows the locations of all the pointers it's dealing with, and can update them when it moves an object.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the standard does not impose how references should be implemented. To catch "dereferenced NULL passed as reference" errors early, you could do this inside your functions(s):

```
void doSomethingWithCustomer (const Customer &customer)
{
  assert(&customer);
  //... rest of function
}
```

Comment: See my comment to Als's answer -- if you do this you should check the emitted code to see whether it gets optimized away.

Comment: @SteveJessop True. However, I would assume `assert()` is only active with optimizations disabled.

Comment: That depends what platforms you're used to, I suppose. Some are better at debugging optimized code that others.